# How to test Exception being thrown with midje

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, midje

Simple question. I'm trying to test in midje if my method triggers an exception. I could only find something like the following in the midje documentation.

```
(fact "Should throw a RuntimeException"
               (my-method! anything) =throws=> (RuntimeException.)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Apart from the small syntax error, isn't that what you want? The documentation says  (fact (explosion) => (throws Exception))

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. I found it.

```
(fact "Should throw a RuntimeException"
           (my-method! anything) => (throws RuntimeException)
```

That works for me.